# Break out of Python loop, without break

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, break

In the below code, why doesn't it stop looping when fighting is set to False?

I know it does not stop looping, because it won't get to the loot part when fighting is set to False. Here is the whole while loop:

```
while fighting:
    cls()
    print("The enemy has", opponent.HP, "HP!")
    input()
    if int(opponent.HP) <= 0:
        print("Yep yep")
        winner = True
        fighting = False
    elif int(ownedCreatures[activeCreature].HP) <= 0:
        winner = False
        fighting = False
    showFight(opponent, activeCreature)
    allowed = ["a", "i", "r"]
    choice = input(">>")

    while not choice in allowed:
        choice = input("Try again please >>")

    if choice.lower() == "a":
        if previousTurn == "Not defined":
            num = random.randint(1, ownedCreatures[activeCreature].support + opponent.support)
            if num <= ownedCreatures[activeCreature].support:
                attacker = "player"
                previousTurn = "player"
            else:
                attacker = "opponent"
                previousTurn = "opponent"
        else:
            if previousTurn == "player":
                attacker = "opponent"
                previousTurn = "opponent"
            else:
                attacker = "player"
                previousTurn = "player"

        attack(attacker, activeCreature, opponent)

    #if choice.lower() == "i":

    if choice.lower() == "r":
        num = random.randint(1, ownedCreatures[activeCreature].support + opponent.support)
        if num <= ownedCreatures[activeCreature].support:
            cls()
            print("-------------------------------------------")
            print("You succesfully escaped this horrible fight!")
            print("-------------------------------------------\n")
            input("Press Enter to continue... >> ")
            winner = "Not defined"
            fighting = False
        else:
            cls()
            print("-------------------------------------------")
            print("Think you can run that easily?")
            print("-------------------------------------------\n")
            input("Press Enter to continue... >> ")

#After the fight
if winner == True:
    cls()
    loot()
elif winner == False:
    cls()
    print("-------------------------------------------")
    print("You have lost the fight!")
    print("You lost 50 Serra!")
    serra = serra - 50
    if serra < 0:
        serra = 0
    print("-------------------------------------------\n")
    input("Press Enter to continue... >> ")
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't stop? Is this all you do inside `while` loop?

Comment: Could you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please print the value of `opponent.HP`

Comment: @RicardoFrederiks can you print the value for those: `opponent.HP`, `ownedCreatures[activeCreature].HP`,  `ownedCreatures[activeCreature].support + opponent.support`

Comment: ownedCreatures[activeCreature].support, opponent.support

Answer (score 1):

You have three places inside the loop where you set `fighting`  to `False` and all of them coming with an `if` condition:

1. `int(opponent.HP) <= 0`
2. `int(ownedCreatures[activeCreature].HP) <= 0`
3. `num <= ownedCreatures[activeCreature].support`

The first and the second conditions are constant inside the loop, so if they start `False`, the change of `fighting` will never be accessible.

The third: `num` is a random number greater than `1` so if `ownedCreatures[activeCreature].support` is `0`, the condition will never be accessible.

Print the values of conditions to check if they are fulfilled or not.

Comment: OP says "why doesn't it stop looping when fighting is set to False" so I presume he is sure it was set to `False`.

Comment: I indeed am sure that the HP is lower or equal to 0. I have checked it with prints and input()'s.

Comment: And when i put a "break" it does work, but i do not want to use a break.

Comment: @RicardoFrederiks you should post the whole code , you have shown us the `if` without the `else`!

Comment: @bigOTHER There is no else in the loot part if that is what you mean?

Comment: I meant the `elif` after `if int(opponent.HP) <= 0`, you cut the code in a critical line